# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pm2

Necesito ayuda!! Tengo un error en mi app Subida en Digitalocean que produce que pm2 reinicie mi app de nodejs, cuando lo hace me tira el siguiente mensaje

```
 pm2 has been killed by signal, dumping process list before exit...
PM2      | Deleting process 0
PM2      | Stopping app:app id:0
PM2      | App [app:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
PM2      | pid=9559 msg=process killed
PM2      | Exited peacefully
PM2      | App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (9678)
PM2      |     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1380:5)
PM2      |     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ForkMode.js:268:12
PM2      |     at wrapper (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16)
PM2      |     at next (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:96:20)
PM2      |     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
PM2      |     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:186:13)
PM2      |     at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
PM2      |     at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:547:15)
PM2      |     at internal/fs/streams.js:395:12
PM2      |     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:163:23)
PM2      | App [app:0] online
```

No encuentro que puede ser por ningun sitio? alguien ha tenido este problema?

GIT

https://github.com/heb1k0/slac

Comment: Estas creando un Buffer de información el cual no contiene informacion valida, esto hace que tu script este fallando, pero sin el codigo mucho no podemos hacer... el error nos dice que falla, mas nosotros no podemos resolver aquello sin tu codigo detras, para conocer que esta fallando...

Comment: Ahora amplio informacion

Comment: He subido un repositorio a github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error se estaba dando por compatibilidad con la `keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine` image de pm2. Estaba compilando el proyecto con unas version de node diferente y eso daba el problema.

Espero que mi solucion te sea de utilidad, simplemente decidi usar `keymetrics/pm2:12-alpine` instead.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Quité el viejo pm2 y lo reinstalé:

desinstalado con:

```
pm2 unstartup
pm2 kill
npm remove pm2 -g
rm -rf ˜/.pm2
```

instalado con:

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
```